# Next.js: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, apexcharts

I'm trying to use apexcharts for a next.js application and it's returning me window is not defined.

I would love any help with that.

Does someone know what is happening and why?

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from 'react-apexcharts';

export default class Graficos extends React.Component <{}, { options: any, series: any }> {
    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            options: {
            chart: {
                id: "basic-bar"
            },
            xaxis: {
                categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
            }
            },
            series: [
            {
                name: "series-1",
                data: [30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91]
            }
            ]
        };
    }
  
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <h1>Gráfico Básico</h1>
                <div className="mixed-chart">
                    <Chart
                        options={this.state.options}
                        series={this.state.series}
                        type="bar"
                        width={500}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Rather than snippets of code, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One of Next.js's key features is that it can render parts of your React application on the server or even at build time. While this can be helpful in improving your page's performance, the downside is that the server does not provide the all same APIs that your application would have access to in the browser. In this case, there is no global `window` object defined.

Unfortunately, searching the source code for apexcharts.js turns up many references to `window`: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/search?q=window. This also occurs in their React wrapper: https://github.com/apexcharts/react-apexcharts/blob/ecf67949df058e15db2bf244e8aa30d78fc8ee47/src/react-apexcharts.jsx#L5. While there doesn't seem to be a way to get apexcharts to avoid references to `window`, you can prevent Next.js from using the chart on the server. The simplest way to do that is to wrap any reference to the code with a check for whether `window` is defined, e.g.

```
<div className="mixed-chart">
  {(typeof window !== 'undefined') &&
  <Chart
    options={this.state.options}
    series={this.state.series}
    type="bar"
    width={500}
  />
  }
</div>
```

With apexcharts, you will also need to do this for the component import because the import alone will trigger a reference to `window` as shown in that second link. In order to get around that problem you will need to use a dynamic import as opposed to the normal import you currently have: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Chart = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });
```

Answer (score 8):

I encountered a type mismatch issue when working with dynamic imports with TypeScript did not work for me in [Next.js 13](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13). However, I resolved it by creating a new component called ApexChart.

In the new ApexChart component, I imported the `react-apexcharts` library and passed the required props to it. Here is an example of what the component looks like:

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function ApexChart(props: any) {
  const [Chart, setChart] = useState<any>();
  const hasType = typeof props?.type !== "undefined";

  useEffect(() => {
    import("react-apexcharts").then((mod) => {
      setChart(() => mod.default);
    });
  }, []);

  return hasType && Chart && <Chart {...props} />;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    host = window.location.host;
    console.log("host--------------", host);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem while using echarts in Nextjs.
Echarts also contains lots of "window"s which make server side crash.
A simple way to solve this is to use "dynamic import" for **any** component that uses echarts and disable ssr.

```js
const EChartsMap = dynamic(() => import('./EchartsMap'),   { ssr: false })
```

Comment: It worked for me in nextjs.

Answer (score -1):

Why `document` or `window` is not defined in `next.js`?

```
function MyComponent() {
  // useMemo will run in server-side & client-side
  // Error: window is not defined in server
  const color = useMemo(()=> {
    return window.globalColor; 
  }, [])
  return <h1 className={`title ${color}`}>Hello World!</h1>
}
```

To fix this issue, you need to use useEffect to run the render only in the client-side.
Here's an example code snippet:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    setColor(window.globalColor)
  }, [])
  return <h1 className={`title ${color}`}>Hello World!</h1>
}
```

Furthermore, wrap the solution above in a hook

```
function useClientMemo<T>(fn: () => T, deps?: DependencyList): T {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<T>();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setData(fn());
  }, deps);
  return data;
}
export default useClientMemo;
```

Then, simply use:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const color = useClientMemo(()=> {
    return window.globalColor; 
  }, [])
  return <h1 className={`title ${color}`}>Hello World!</h1>
}
```

Explanation:

- useEffect is executed only during client-side rendering.
- useMemo is executed during both client-side rendering and server-side rendering.