# Mathquill on NextJS 13.3.0 or any solution to dynamically show math on browser with Next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, latex, server-side-rendering

I am building a webapp that uses LaTeX writable by user in some input to dynamically show it into another div or replacing it in the same input.

I've been trying to use Mathquill with NextJS v13.3.0, and I found this npm package that solves that for React called "React-Mathquill" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathquill), but this does not work beacuse of SSR (Server Side Rendering) according to the author, and he suggest to import the package without SSR (https://github.com/viktorstrate/react-mathquill/issues/49). The thing is, I quite do not understand how to do this, I've read the documentation according to NoSSR (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr) but seems a bit complex to understand and make unsure on how to do it.

If someone knows how to solve this or has a different solution with another library or something to show complex math equations (even without LaTeX) compatible with Next, I would thank you for share it

Here's what I tried:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { addStyles, EditableMathField } from 'react-mathquill'

addStyles()

function Test() 
{
    const [latex, setLatex] = useState('\\frac{1}{\\sqrt{2}}\\cdot 2')

    return (
        <div>

          <EditableMathField
            latex={latex}
            onChange={(mathField) => {
              setLatex(mathField.latex())
            }}
          />

          <p>{latex}</p>

        </div>
      )
}

export default Test
```

but this error shows up:

> ```
> Server Error
> ReferenceError: window is not defined
> ```

Comment: I am not sure. You can try "const EditableMathField = dynamic(() => import("react-mathquill"), { ssr: false })".

Comment: I don't know what happend, recently what you said worked just fine, but now it's not. I just added the line next to the imports and worked for a moment

Comment: I found out, the problem was `addStyles()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post [Next.js: window is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596778/next-js-window-is-not-defined), some libraries do references to `window` just by being imported, so they must be used by another way, in this case, the function `addStyles` was the problem. Since MathQuill provides its stylesheet, I was able to add it from the `public` folder of the proyect this way

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Head from 'next/head';

const EditableMathField = dynamic(() => import("react-mathquill"), { ssr: false })

function Test() 
{
    const [latex, setLatex] = useState('\\frac{1}{\\sqrt{2}}\\cdot 2')

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mathquill.css"/>
            </Head>   

            <div>

                <EditableMathField
                    latex={latex}
                    onChange={(mathField) => 
                        {
                            setLatex(mathField.latex())
                        }}
                />

                <p>{latex}</p>

            </div>
        </>
      )
}

export default Test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"use client";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { MathField } from "react-mathquill";

const EditableMathField = dynamic(
  () => import("react-mathquill").then((mod) => mod.EditableMathField),
  { ssr: false }
);

const YourComponent = () => {
 
  useEffect(() => {
    import("react-mathquill").then((mq) => {
      mq.addStyles();
    });
  }, []);

// ...rest of your component

}
```

You can import addStyles like this. I ran into a similar issue, Next.js also discourages the use of manual style sheet tags in components so using Head is not recommended I guess

Answer (score 0):

After researchig other libraries and some failure, I found MathJax and made this solution which reanalyze every element of the page when the specified LaTeX change:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Test() 
{
    const [latex, setLatex] = useState("");

    const handleChange = ( { target: { value } }) =>
    {   
        setLatex(value)
    }

    const mathJaxReanalyze = async () => 
    {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.MathJax) 
        {
            try
            {
                await window.MathJax.typesetPromise();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                console.log("MatJax error: " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        mathJaxReanalyze();
    }, [latex])

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
                <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
            </Head>

            <div>
                
                <input onChange={handleChange}/>

                <p>{latex}</p>

            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Test
```

It is not as clean as using MathQuill would have been, but works for me

**EDIT:** Recently noticed the comment with the solution, but I will leave this answer if someone finds it useful